# javascript and use php conditioning

Tags: javascript, php, conditional-statements

#### First problem

I want to use variable `don_settings[don_btn_act]` (=checkbox) to define a button action.

```
IF don_settings[don_btn_act] IS on
THEN -> load checkout
ELSE -> page reload
```

`don_settings[don_btn_act]` is definded and it is modified well, so i can turn it on or off. The problem is that I should use it in javascript.

What I have so far:

```
function reloadpage(){
  <?php if(isset($don_config['don_btn_act']) && $don_config['don_btn_act'] =='on') { ?>
    window.location.href = 'index.php?route=dcheckout/checkout';
  <?php } else { ?>
    window.location.reload();
  <?php } ?>    
}
```

It is always executing the `window.location.reload()` function.

#### Second problem

in the same way i have the variable `don_settings[min_amount]`. I use it to define the minimum amount of input.
it is defined in php like the previous varible.
But i should use it in javascript part of tpl file, too.

What I have so far:

```
function validation(){
    if(jQuery('#opton').val() == ''){
        alert("<?php echo $drop_empty_msg; ?>");
        return false;
    }
    else if(jQuery('#don_amount').val() == '' || jQuery('#don_amount').val() == '0'){
        alert("<?php echo $amount_empty; ?>");
        jQuery('#don_amount').focus();
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

i use

```
|| jQuery('#don_amount').val() <= "<?php $don_settings[min_amount]; ?>"
```

insteed of

```
|| jQuery('#don_amount').val() == '0'
```

but it returns false every time

Comment: do you need to reload the page when checking on checkbox

Comment: no when the checkbox is checked i need to run : window.location.href = 'index.php?route=dcheckout/checkout'; and when it is not i need to run :window.location.reload(); both commands work fine but the conditioning is not working main problem is how to state and use $don_config['don_btn_act']) in script part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I couldn't understand your problem or your intensions. Try correcting your misspelling, your grammar and please take care of beautiful formatted code!

Nonetheless i have some recommendations for writing maintainable code.

#### Your problem (#1)

If your browser is always executing the `window.location.reload()`, the problem does not refer to your javascript. **It is your server side code which fails.** Your following condition seems to be false:

```
<?php if(isset($don_config['don_btn_act']) && $don_config['don_btn_act'] =='on') { ?>
```

#### Don't mix your javascript and php up

First of all, compute your necessary values/conditions:
  *(Preferably into a seperated file)*

```
<?php
  $condition = isset($don_config['don_btn_act']) && $don_config['don_btn_act'] =='on';
?>
```

Now, you can use it very comfortable and clearly:

```
function reloadpage() {
  var condition = '<?php echo $condition; ?>';

  if (condition)
    window.location.href = 'index.php?route=dcheckout/checkout';
  else
    window.location.reload();
}
```

There are lots of big advantages not to mess up your code.

#### Also be careful ...

... while injecting code through php to the markup/javascript. Don't offer potential attackers new security holes!

Comment: first sorry about my bad englishThank you

Comment: You don't have to apologise for that. Nobody is perfect ;)

Comment: Thank you.I just add ' to your code  : var condition = '<?php echo $condition; ?>'; and every thing work well